# edit html text with domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

Given a partial HTML fragment such as

```
<div id="article">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
    <pre><code>
         echo $variable;
    </code></pre>
</div>
```

I want to loop through the text nodes and apply a function to them, doesn't really matter what the function does, but not if its the text in the pre code block.

Given it's a partial code block I think I need to use `DOMDocument->createDocumentFragment()`. But how can I loop through the text nodes then save the output without extra `<html>` tags being created, as `saveHTML()` seems to do by default?

Comment: use jquery append().. to append by an event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a document fragment.  Looping over the text nodes is the easy part, finding them is a little tricker.  For that, the example below uses an XPath query to find all text nodes that are not descendants of the `<pre>` element.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML(<<<'HTML'
<div id="article">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>More text</p>
    <pre><code>
         echo $variable;
    </code></pre>
</div>
HTML
);

$text_nodes = $xpath->query('descendant::text()[not(ancestor::pre)]', $frag);
foreach ($text_nodes as $text_node) {
    $text_node->data = strrev($text_node->data);
}

// Print the div
echo $doc->saveHTML($frag->firstChild);
```

This will print out something like:

```
<div id="article">    
<p>txet emoS</p>    
<p>txet eroM</p>    
<pre><code>
         echo $variable;
    </code></pre>
</div>
```

Helpful links:

- [`DOMText` `data` property](http://php.net/domcharacterdata#domcharacterdata.props.data) (`DOMText` extends `DOMCharacterData)
- [XPath for PHP guide](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html)
- [Play with the above example online](http://3v4l.org/R1Xti)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using DomDocument?

Why not read the HTML from the 'remote source' and then save it as a file on the server using file_put_contents()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php